# Is there a way to have multiple projects referenced in one solution with Azure Devops?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio, azure-devops

The way our projects are set up is we have multiple separated by whether they are internal or external facing applications, however, we have a set of data projects which house our various classes and models needed to read and write certain items into the database.  This is what we call the data access layer of our applications and it is three separate projects that exist in one folder on our internal server and from there we reference the .csproj files within those applications into our other projects/applications so that we can use them anywhere.  With this setup we are able to have these project file exist in one place on our server and are able to build, debug, and publish any of our applications to the server we want them to run on.

Project file structure:

1. parent solution/application
   A. primary .csproj file (same name as solution)
   B. Reference to .csproj 1
   C. Reference to .csproj 2
   D. Reference to .csproj 3

I am able to push the code within the parent solution up to Azure Devops and I can have source control for it however, what I would like to do is publish to a hosted Azure web app instance from Devops.  Whenever I try to create a pipeline within Devops to build the project, the build fails because the referenced files for the data projects cannot be found.  I have looked into the path filters but I do not understand how they work or how to implement them in my current situation.  Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an optimal case for you be producing a NuGet package of your shared data contracts in the form of a class library and publishing that as a private artifact in Azure DevOps using a pipeline.

That way, instead of each solution requiring direct access to the project, they can take a package dependency that Azure will have access to during builds across your internal repositories. Any time you push a new commit for your shared contract library, ADO can complete a build and iterate the NuGet package version, and you can access these private NuGet packages from your local machine when authenticated to ADO as if they were coming from Nuget.org.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam I'm going to look into this and if I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey @AdamG how do I create the artifact? do I publish the project that I want shared into Devops or am I suppose to add an action to the Pipepline in my parent solution to get it to build an artifact.  I only ask because in that tutorial you posted it looks like it's asking me to target just all CSproj files and those files are not in the parent  solutions repo on Devops.